# Rails 3 - Update Parent Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, controller

I have a `Trans` (transaction) class in my application that submits a transaction to the server.  When a transaction is submitted, I also want to do an update on a parent User class to update their cached "balance."  Here is relevant code:

```
# tran.rb
class Tran < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :submitting_user, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

And my controller:

```
#trans_controller.rb
def create
        @title = "Create Transaction"

        # Add the transaction from the client
        @tran = Tran.new(params[:tran])

        # Update the current user
        @tran.submitting_user_id = current_user.id

        # ERROR: This line is not persisted
        @tran.submitting_user.current_balance = 4;

        # Save the transaction
        if @tran.save
            flash[:success] = 'Transaction was successfully created.'
            redirect_to trans_path
```

I have a couple of problems:

1. When I update the current_balance field on the user, that balance isn't persisted on the user after the transaction is saved.  I think maybe I need to use `update_attributes`?
2. I am not even sure that the code should be a part of my controller - maybe it makes more sense in the `before_save` of my model?
3. Will either of these make this transactional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create
  title = "Create Transaction"
  @tran = Tran.new(params[:tran])
  @tran.submitting_user_id = current_user.id
  # to make it "transactional" you should put it after @tran.save
  if @tran.save
    current_user.update_attribute :current_balance, 4
    ...
```

And yes - it is better to put it into `after_save` callback

```
class Tran < AR::Base
  after_save :update_user_balance

  private
  def update_user_balance
    submitting_user.update_attribute :current_balance, 4
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  Will this make it transactional?  If not, how can I do that?  Also, should this really be code in the controller, or encapsulated in the tran model?  Thanks again.

Comment: It won't be executed if `@tran` won't be save - if that is "transactional" for you

Comment: But it would then be possible for the update_user_balance to bomb, right?  So the save would commit but the update would not?

Comment: Yes, in that way - yes. You can try to use [AR.transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html). But I've never used is